# Adobe Premiere & Final Cut Pro project file standard?

Tags: file-formats, premiere, final-cut-pro

Is there a standard for non-linear video project files? I want to create a slideshow of my life using jpg + mp3 files and want to be able to tweak it many years from now. My fear is that if I use Adobe Premiere, it will not be easy to migrate to Final Cut Pro or vice versa or whatever file format is used in the industry standard application in the future.

It's not like having txt files which you can be reasonably sure will still be editable 20 years from now.

Answer (score 4):

FCP can export an XML file that contains the basics of your sequence. Premiere can then import this and create a native project file based on the contents of that XML. I'm pretty sure Premiere can also export a similar file for import/conversion into FCP (I haven't tried though).

It's worth noting that the formats are likely to change considerably years down the line, to the extent that a later version of the same software package may not be able to open it. You're best bet is to make sure all the individual files are archived so that if you're in that situation, you can just start over with the same files.

Answer (score 3):

To be fully honest, it's impossible to tell.

Even now, there's a bit of an industry battle between FCP (which is dead following FCX), Premiere and AVID.

Your best bet would be to edit in Premiere and keep an ear out, upgrading every 3-4 years with Premiere and possible emigrating the project over to whatever NLE is the industry standard at that time.

---

**Update 120703 @ 1604**

Having reread the question, mp3 + jpg images - why not use PowerPoint?

Comment: 7 years on, I just saw the PowerPoint question. I'd avoid non plaintext files because I can't tweak them with a text editor. Then again the pptx format has plaintext bit somehow I'm not comfortable with a multi file plaintext archive